# Gradle combine Flavors + release/debug

Tags: android, gradle

I want use something like this, i know that's not possible, but i wanna know if have another way to use combine Flavor With build type

```
productFlavors{
    demo{
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "URL", '"192.1.1.1"'
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "URL", '"192.2.2.2"'
        }
    }
    full{
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "URL", '"192.2.2.2"'
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "URL", '"192.3.3.3"'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than product flavors you can create multiple build types to suit your requirement. 
for eg create build types like below

```
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL", '"192.2.2.2"'
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL", '"192.3.3.3"'
    }

    releasedemo {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL", '"192.1.1.1"'
    }
    debugdemo {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL", '"192.2.2.2"'
    }
```

Comment: but in android studio will generate a releasedemoDebug and releasedemoRelease it will be a mess

Comment: If you do this in build types there would be only four releases. release,demo,releasedemo and debugdemo.